# Задание по JS. Нужна адекватная критика

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем привет. **Кодил** я на `Python`, хотел всегда освоить дальше `js`. Знал какие-то базовые моменты. Недавно прислали мне задания, что бы проверить уровень знаний `js`. Сел написал первый свой код на js.

> По итогу получил **фидбек:** задания выполнены неверно, потренеруйтесь
>   и попробуйте снова.

Так вот суть вопроса в том, что я не против потренироваться, но мне нужен совет, что не так было сделано и что в конце концов я должен тренировать `write`.

Просто по факту все функции выполняют то, что требовалось в заданиях. Прошу вас глянуть и сказать в чем проблема то, может я действительно не правильно понял задания, либо же я как-то не по `js-ий` их выполнил, или не правильно оформил код. Всем заранее спасибо за ответ, а то ответ `"задания выполнены неверно"` не дает по ночам спать спокойно.

> Задания:
>   1. In JavaScript write a function summing all array elements.

```
 function arraySum(array) {
     // your code goes here
 }
 arraySum([1, 2, 3, 4]) // 10
```

---

> 2. Let's separate array iteration and an operation to be done.  Write a function folding an array with any given function.

```
   function fold(array, operation) {
        // your code goes here
    }
    function add(a, b) { return a + b }
    function mul(a, b) { return a * b }
    fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add) // add(add(add(1, 2), 3), 4) === 10
    fold([1, 2, 3, 4], mul) // 24
```

---

> 3. Add an optional parameter to start folding with.

```
function fold(array, operation, initial) {
    // your code goes here
    // hint: use arguments.length
}
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add) // 10
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, 10) // add(add(add(add(10, 1), 2), 3), 4) === 20
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], mul, 10) // 240
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, '10') // '101234'
```

---

> 4. Write the same fold function recursively.  Do not simulate cycle via recursion.

```
function fold(array, operation, initial) {

    // your code goes here
    // hint: use array.slice

}
```

---

А вот сам код решений:

**Task 1**

```js
 

function arraySum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  };
  alert(sum);
}
arraySum([2, 4, 3]);
```

---

**Task 2**

```js
function arraySum(array, operation) {
  var answer = array[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (operation == '+') {
      answer += array[i];
    } else if (operation == '-') {
      answer -= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '*') {
      answer *= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '/') {
      answer /= array[i];
    }
  }
  alert(answer);
}
arraySum([1, 2, 3, 4], '/');
```

---

**Task 3**

```js
function arraySum(array, operation, initial) {
  if (typeof initial == 'string') {
    var answer = initial + array.join('');
  }

  if (initial == undefined) {
    var answer = array[0];
  } else if (operation == '+') {
    var answer = initial + array[0];
  } else if (operation == '-') {
    var answer = initial - array[0];
  } else if (operation == '*') {
    var answer = initial * array[0];
  } else if (operation == '/') {
    var answer = initial / array[0];
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (operation == '+') {
      answer += array[i];
    } else if (operation == '-') {
      answer -= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '*') {
      answer *= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '/') {
      answer /= array[i];
    }
  }
  alert(answer);
}
arraySum([1, 2, 3, 4], '+', '10');
```

---

**Task 4**

```js
function arraySum(array, operation, initial) {
  function startAnswer() {
    if (typeof initial == 'string') {
      var answer = initial + array.join('');
    }

    if (initial == undefined) {
      var answer = array[0];
    } else if (operation == '+') {
      var answer = initial + array[0];
    } else if (operation == '-') {
      var answer = initial - array[0];
    } else if (operation == '*') {
      var answer = initial * array[0];
    } else if (operation == '/') {
      var answer = initial / array[0];
    }
    return answer;
  }

  var answer = startAnswer()

  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (operation == '+') {
      answer += array[i];
    } else if (operation == '-') {
      answer -= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '*') {
      answer *= array[i];
    } else if (operation == '/') {
      answer /= array[i];
    }
  }
  alert(answer);
}
arraySum([1, 2, 3, 4], '+');
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0nd1l0FRa2lAe6YelpKr8crri24_2-P/view?usp=sharing

Понятно, что может `условий- if()` слишком много, можно было как-то более элегантно сделать? 
Но это первый код на 'js' с базовыми знаниями. Правильно ли задания решены?

Всем спасибо за адекватную критику.

Comment: Bogdan Degtyar, сей сайт русскоязычный, советую, задания приведенные в примере написанные на английском, перевести на русский... Можно оставить оригинал, Но перевести обязательно...  Я не так хорош в инглише и не стал трогать английский текст

Comment: Вы выполнили второе задание абсолютно не так, в условии второй параметр - функция, вы же делаете свитч по строке. Оно, соответственно, потянуло за собой в пропасть третье и четвертое задания.

Comment: Чем `reduce` метод не устраивает?

Answer (score 2):

Все кроме последнего нацелены на использование функции reduce, она позволяет вычислять значение на базе массива, объяснять как работает нет смысла, найдете документацию.

1.

```js
 function arraySum(array) {
     return array.reduce((acc, val) => (acc + val), 0)
 }
arraySum([1, 2, 3, 4]) // 10
```

2. начиная с этого и последующие вы делали не то, под operation подразумевается функция, которая будет выполнять операцию (add, mul)

```js
  function fold(array, operation) {
        return array.reduce((acc, val) => operation(acc, val))
  }
  function add(a, b) { return a + b }
  function mul(a, b) { return a * b }
  fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add) // add(add(add(1, 2), 3), 4) === 10
  fold([1, 2, 3, 4], mul) // 24
```

3. ```js
   function fold(array, operation, initial) {
       return initial 
         ? array.reduce((acc, val) => operation(acc, val), initial)
         : array.reduce((acc, val) => operation(acc, val))
   }
   const add = (a, b) => (a + b)
   const mul = (a, b) => (a * b)
   fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add) // 10
   fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, 10) // add(add(add(add(10, 1), 2), 3), 4) === 20
   fold([1, 2, 3, 4], mul, 10) // 240
   fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, '10') // '101234'
   ```
4. тут нужно было использовать рукурсию

```js
function fold(array, operation, initial) {
    initial = initial || 0
    const val = operation(initial, array.shift())
    if (array.length) return fold(array, operation, val)
    return val
}
const add = (a, b) => (a + b)
const mul = (a, b) => (a * b)
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add) // 10
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, 10) // add(add(add(add(10, 1), 2), 3), 4) === 20
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], mul, 10) // 240
fold([1, 2, 3, 4], add, '10') // '101234'
```

Comment: Первое задание можно было еще короче: `return array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)`, потому что в 3-м Вы немного неправы, если второй параметр в `reduce` не задан, то берется первый элемент массива, а перебор начинается со второго. :)

Comment: @Yaant в третьем согласен, правда использование arguments.length все равно в данном случае не нравиться,
а в первом специально добавил, для наглядности